# Getting debug session timeout trying to debug Android junit tests

Tags: java, android, debugging, junit, connection-timeout

I'm trying to debug Android junit tests. I can set break points in a test or in the code under test and they get hit. However, there is a one minute timeout that ends the debug session. I've looked at using @LargeTest instead of @SmallTest since it is suppose to have a 5 minute timeout, but I see no difference. My colleague has the same problem, so it's not just my machine. How can I disable the junit 1 minute timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Add following syntax to the test case:

```
@Rule
public TestRule timeout = new DisableOnDebug(new Timeout(20));
```

Reference:
https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/DisableOnDebug.html

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this rule in  the class containing your tests:

```
@Rule
    public Timeout globalTimeout = new Timeout(10000); // 10 seconds max per method tested
```

Source: https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests

Note : Put debug point on respective test case also to enable Junit in debug mode

Comment: Thanks for response. However, the org.junit package (for @Rule) does not appear to be available for Android unit tests. Nor can Eclipse resolve Timeout class.  I did make progress though. I was using the android emulator. When I switch to using a real device, I don't have the timeout problem. So this appears to be an emulator related problem.